# Yii CDbCriteria query matching mutiple rows in one table

Tags: mysql, yii

I'm trying to figure out how to build a query using Yii's CDbCriteria that would be equivalent to the following:

```
 SELECT 
        * 
FROM 
        user u 
JOIN ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM skill_assessment s 
        WHERE s.skill = 'HTML' 
        AND s.score >= 80 
) b ON 
        (u.id = b.userId) 
JOIN ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM skill_assessment s 
        WHERE s.skill = 'CSS3' 
        AND s.score >= 80
) c ON 
        (u.id = c.userId);
etc...
```

Here's what I have so far, that isn't working:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->alias = "u";
$criteria->select = "*";
$criteria->join = "JOIN skill_assessment s ON (u.id=s.userId)";
for($i = 0; $i < count($skill_filters); $i++) {
    $criteria->addCondition("s.skill='".$skill_filters[$i]->skill."' AND s.score >= ".$skill_filters[$i]->level);
}

$users = UserModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I was able to build out the sql query as a string and use findAllBySql, which returned the correct UserModels that matched my search criteria, the problem is that I haven't been able to get it to return the related SkillAssessmentModels. They don't come back either with the initial query, like this:

```
$users = UserModel::model()->with('skill_assessments')->findAllBySql($sql);
```

nor if I get the results like this:

```
$users = UserModel::model->findAllBySql($sql);
foreach($users as $user)
{
     $user->skill_assessments = $user->getRelated('skill_assessments');
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can get those related models?
The strange thing is that elsewhere in my application, I CAN get the related models if I do this:

```
$user = UserModel::model->findByPk($id);
$user->skill_assessments->getRelated('skill_assessments');
```

Comment: You could read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Boris Belenski!
What you suggested wasn't *quite* what I needed, but it did get me to what I needed. Here is what I ended up with that works:

```
$str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            $idxs = str_split($str);

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->alias = "u";
            $joins = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < count($skill_filters); $i++)
            {
                $joins[] = " JOIN (SELECT * FROM skill_assessment s WHERE s.skill = '" . $skill_filters[$i]->skill ."' AND s.score >= " . $skill_filters[$i]->level . ") " . $idxs[$i] . " ON (u.id = " . $idxs[$i] . ".userId) ";
            }

            $criteria->join = join(' ', $joins);
            $users = UserModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                $user->skill_assessments = $user->getRelated('skill_assessments');
            }
```

The really key part is that $joins array.
This will allow you to get all the users that match ALL the criteria for row matches in the skill_assessments table.

Also, I could probably lazily load the skill assessments in the View in a normal view, but I need to get all the skill_assessments for each user now in order to pass them back in an ajax response with the user.

Answer (score 2):

Second param for `addCondition` is by default `'AND'`. Is this what you are looking for? May be you should define `'OR'` for `$operator` and add braces around condition.
But in your case `addCondition` will by applied to the *user* table, not to the *JOIN*.

I think that this should work for you:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->alias = "u";
$criteria->together= "skill_assessment";
$where = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($skill_filters); $i++) {
    $where[] = "(s.skill='".$skill_filters[$i]->skill."' AND s.score >= ".$skill_filters[$i]->level . ')';
}
$criteria->join = 'JOIN skill_assessment s ON (u.id=s.userId' . ( $where ? ( ' AND (' . join( ' OR ', $where ) . ')' ) : '') . ')';

$users = UserModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Fetch _skill_assessment_ like this:

```
foreach( $users->skill_assessment as $skill_assessment )
{
    echo $skill_assessment->userId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this level keep it simple:

```
$sql="select * from mytable where id = :id";
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->bindParam("id", $res_id);
$cmd->execute();
```

Comment: Please see my edit to the original post regarding building the SQL manually.

Comment: Please try if that works by adding the `together` flag. `with('skill_assessments')->together()->`